# Is there a way to find which user run what application on a server using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to find a way to find out who has ran an application (for example SQL) on a server, just to get some idea.

I tried Get-Process but this doesn't give me historic information, I want to get historical information

Get-Process -IncludeUserName *

what I want the return resule is "name of application", "user who ran it" and the last datetime it was ran by that user'

Comment: Look up the docs on event logs then check the PS commands that can iterate through them

Comment: I don't think logging is enabled for that by default. If it is, your security audit logs will have that info and you can use `get-winevent` [recommemded since its fast] or `get-eventlog` to scan through those.

Answer (score 0):

As for ...

> I am trying to find a way to find out who has ran an application (for
>   example SQL) on a server, just to get some idea.

What you are asking for here is software metering.
SQL is a service that is always running once it is installed, so, no individual user is ever going to be running it. So, that is a bad example. MS Word for example would be a better example.

Yet there is nothing native in PowerShell that does this, software metering, but of course PowerShell can look at event logs. Yet if your auditing is not setup correctly then it's moot. This is better for a software metering tool, and there are several out there. So, why try and reinvent the wheel.

As for ...

> I tried Get-Process but this doesn't give me historic information, I
>   want to get historical information

That is not what a process is nor what Get-Process is for. It, Get-Process only checks for and lists whatever process is currently running, regardless of what/who launched it.

As for...

> what I want the return resule is "name of application", "user who ran
>   it" and the last datetime it was ran by that user'

As long as the process is running, you can get this, with that cmdlet.
However, what are you trying to accomplish by this?

Again, there are purpose built tools to meter software use.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/apps/deploy-use/monitor-app-usage-with-software-metering

If you must go down this reinvent the wheel road, using scripting, then you need a task watcher on the target machines, which watches for the WinWord process to appear.

Get-Process -IncludeUserName | 
Where ProcessName -EQ 'Winword'

... you then write those results to a file or database or your own event log each time you see that process.

[Use PowerShell to Create and to Use a New Event Log](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-and-to-use-a-new-event-log/)

```
New-EventLog -LogName ScriptingGuys -Source scripts
```

> When the command runs, no output appears to the Windows PowerShell console. To ensure the command actually created a new event log, I use
>   the Get-EventLog cmdlet with the –List parameter. Here is the command
>   and the associated output.

```
Write-EventLog -LogName ScriptingGuys -Source scripts -Message “Dude, it works … COOL!” -EventId 0 -EntryType information
```

Or just to a file

```
Get-Process -IncludeUserName | 
Where ProcessName -EQ 'Winword' | 
Select-Object -Property Name, StartTime, Username | 
Export-Csv -Path 'F:\Temp\AppLaunchLog.csv' -Append

Import-Csv -Path 'F:\Temp\AppLaunchLog.csv'

# Results

Name    StartTime            UserName   
----    ---------            --------   
WINWORD 5/23/2019 9:02:53 PM WS01\LabUser001
```